# Does WeakReference<> helps with GC on this specific scenario?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, lifecycle, weak-references

I'm not sure if this will give me some memory leak problems in the long run, and I'm wondering if it makes any difference to use a weakreference in this scenario:

```
public abstract class ChangeObserver<X extends SomeClass> {

   X someClass;

   public ChangeObserver(X someClass) {
       this.someClass= someClass;
   }

   public void notifySomeClass(
   ) {
       onChanged().onChanged(someClass);
   }

   public abstract OnDataChanged<X> onChanged();

   @FunctionalInterface
   public interface OnDataChanged<X> {
       void onChanged(X x);
   }

}
```

will this cause problems in the program's lifecycle? would it get resolved simply by using a weakreference?

Thanks to @Hulk and @tashkhisi I've come with this solution, If, there is something missing, please don't hesitate on correcting it.

```
public abstract class ChangeObserver<X extends SomeClass> {

    private WeakReference<X> someClassWeakRef;
    private OnDataChanged<X> observer;

    public ChangeObserver(X someClass) {
        this.someClassWeakRef = new WeakReference<>(someClass);
        observer = onChanged();
    }

    public void notifySomeClass(
    ) {
        observer.onChanged(someClassWeakRef.get());
    }

    public abstract OnDataChanged<X> onChanged();

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface OnDataChanged<X> {
        void onChanged(X x);
    }

}
```

What I'm still missing is what exactly does this removeObserver() method should do to **remove** the observer, If I were to use that specific method of avoiding memory leaks, is it just simply setting the observer = null ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of leaks do you expect? And which reference do you consider to turn into a `WeakReference` - `someClass`?

Comment: And what exactly is `onChanged()` (the first one)?

Comment: Hi @Hulk, thanks for your attention, If the enclosing class of this object gets destroyed, wouldn't the reference to SomeClass in this object prevent the entire enclosing class to get GC?
onChanged() (the first one) is the abstract method call for the construction/init of the interface.

Comment: The reference `someClass` can keep the referred Object alive, but if the Object derived from `ChangeObserver` is no longer referenced from anywhere else, this reference won't change its lifetime. Even if there are circular references - most Java GC implementations handle circles fine, as long as there are no more refernces from the "outside".

Comment: @Hulk "And which reference do you consider to turn into a WeakReference - someClass" Good question... I was thinking about the only field variable, but maybe the interface, is also a source of leak?, even tho it gets called new every time notify gets called, which I think is bad, and needs to be changed to only be initialized once... I'm definitely gonna change that.

Comment: Either way, I fear this question is a bit too vague to be definitely answerable - we would need a concrete usage szenario, with both the observer and the observed etc. And that would probably be quite a lot of code to read through ;-) I'd recommend to just try it, possibly running it through a profiler to monitor GC and see if there really is a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much @Hulk, I fear that it will indeed cause problems, because of this: "most Java GC mplemntations handle crcles fine,as long as there're no more rfernces from the "outside""

This object is part of a visitor object,that has multiple methods that are called from the outside.

So far I've mnaged to avoid "bringing" any passing vriables "to" the visitor,what I mean is that these vars are never stored as fields, they just pass through.

This is the first instance in which I bring one of them(SomeClass) up front as a field, so I used this apprch cause it seemed less "direct".

Comment: this is such a vague question. "Does WeakReference<> helps with GC..." is exactly the opposite. A GC has to do _more_ work when it encounters a WeakReference, not less.

Answer (score 2):

Yes There are many ways of tackling memory leak in `Observer` Pattern in Java one of them is to add another method like `removeObserver` to your class for removing Observer object from `Observable` when you don't need them any more and the second way is to use Weak reference like below:( I would rather named it `someObject` instead of `someClass` but I have obeyed your naming convention)

```
WeakReference<X> x = new WeakReference<X>(someClass);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @tashkhisi for your answer.

Comment: @Delark This is a terrible answer and to be frank I have no idea how it solves anything. So you wrapped an _instance_ of `X` into a `WeakReference`, so? What does this gives you? And the fact that you left the name as `someClass` (if that is really a `Class<?>` then a WeakReference is _even more_ pointless here), shows that you do not understand what this does. The only point is using a `WeakReference` is to _react_ when the referent is gone (that is `get` returns a `null`), which you have not even remotely explained.